# React Native Realm: How to pre-load realm with 50000 objects

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

Is there a way we can pre-load Realm data base with 50,000 objects. It seems like inserting them takes hours. What could be the best way to have it pre-inserted ?

Comment: That would be a pre-populated aka 'Bundled' realm. It's covered in the [Realm Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm). That's the Swift link but it applies to other platforms when distributing the app.